# Apache/Tomcat/Railo: Setting up two sites with same domain but two different ports

Tags: apache, tomcat, coldfusion, railo

I have successfully setup Railo with Tomcat and Apache for a website on port 80.  I'm however struggling to set another up that uses the same domain but a port other than 80.

I have the second site setup on port 9080 and with a SSL certificate and basic authentication.  I can access it and get the SSL certificate and authentication prompt but once I get through that, Railo is outputting the default page (located at /opt/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/index.cfm).

It's as if Tomcat is not getting from Apache the servername for the second site so Railo knows what docbase to use.  Is it because I'm trying to use the same domain?  Do I need to specify port 9080 somewhere in the Tomcat configuration?

I have pasted my configuration below.  Any help is much appreciated.

**Apache:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sitename
  ServerAlias domainname
  DirectoryIndex index.cfm index.html index.htm

  DocumentRoot "/web/sitename"
  <Directory "/web/sitename">
    allow from all
    Options +Indexes
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Listen 9080
<VirtualHost *:9080>
  ServerName sitename2
  ServerAlias domainname
  DirectoryIndex index.cfm index.html index.htm
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile    /web/ssl/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /web/ssl/server.key

  DocumentRoot "/web/sitename2
  <Directory "/web/sitename2">
    allow from all
    Options -Indexes
    AuthName .. basic auth settings ..
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Tomcat (server.xml):**

```
<Host name="sitename" appBase="webapps">
    <Context path="" docBase="/web/sitename" />
</Host>

<Host name="sitename2" appBase="webapps">
    <Context path="" docBase="/web/sitename2" />
</Host>
```

Comment: How have you connected Apache to Tomcat?  I don't see any AJP or other information saying how you set up Apache to proxy requests and pass them to Tomcat.  Can you include the relevant configuration from Apache?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the Tomcat config. You cannot have two hosts with the same "sitename". One will override the other. Ideally, you would be able to get Tomcat to listen to multiple ports, just like you can with Apache, but Coyote (Tomcat's web server) is not as advanced as Apache is in terms of this kind of functionality. Most of the recommendations I've seen regarding running Tomcat on multiple ports suggest running separate instances of Tomcat on the same machine, so that's what I'd recommend to you as well, as it seems to be what's generally accepted.

If you installed a second instance of Tomcat and installed Railo on it, you could configure Apache to pass requests coming in to your second virtual host to your second instance of Tomcat. For example, you could have your second instance of Tomcat listen with it's AJP listener to port 9009 instead of 8009, and then configure your Apache virtual host to proxy requests to port 9009, thus hitting your second instance of Tomcat.

Then, in your second instance, you could create the same host entries but with the different docbase attribute.

**For example:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sitename
  ServerAlias domainname
  DirectoryIndex index.cfm index.html index.htm

  DocumentRoot "/web/sitename"
  <Directory "/web/sitename">
    allow from all
    Options +Indexes
  </Directory>
  <Proxy *>
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cf[cm])(/.*)?$ ajp://localhost:8009/$1$2
</VirtualHost>

Listen 9080
<VirtualHost *:9080>
  ServerName sitename2
  ServerAlias domainname
  DirectoryIndex index.cfm index.html index.htm
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile    /web/ssl/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /web/ssl/server.key

  DocumentRoot "/web/sitename2
  <Directory "/web/sitename2">
    allow from all
    Options -Indexes
    AuthName .. basic auth settings ..
  </Directory>
  <Proxy *>
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cf[cm])(/.*)?$ ajp://localhost:9009/$1$2
</VirtualHost>
```

It's not a simple answer for what you're doing, but it will accomplish your goal.

-Jordan